# How to Grok a pattern into multiple field names

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

How can I grok a matched pattern into multiple field names?

Is it possible to parse and assign a matched pattern twice with Grok?

**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**

Take this log line:

> 09/26/2019 Keith Miklas

Apply this grok filter:

```
%{DATE:date}\s*%{WORD:first_name}\s*%{WORD:last_name}
```

This yields:

```
{
  "date": [
    [
      "09/26/2019"
    ]
  ],
  "first_name": [
    [
      "Keith"
    ]
  ],
  "last_name": [
    [
      "Miklas"
    ]
  ]
}
```

What I need is a grok filter something like this:

```
%{DATE:date}\s*%{WORD:first_name,fn}\s*%{WORD:last_name,ln}
%{DATE:date}\s*%{WORD:first_name&fn}\s*%{WORD:last_name&ln}
%{DATE:date}\s*%{WORD:first_name|fn}\s*%{WORD:last_name|ln}
```

Yielding this:

```
{
  "date": [
    [
      "09/26/2019"
    ]
  ],
  "first_name": [
    [
      "Keith"
    ]
  ],
  "fn": [
    [
      "Keith"
    ]
  ],
  "last_name": [
    [
      "Miklas"
    ]
  ],
  "ln": [
    [
      "Miklas"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wrap the parts you need with named capturing groups:

```
%{DATE:date}\s*(?<fn>%{WORD:first_name})\s*(?<ln>%{WORD:last_name})
               ^^^^^^                  ^   ^^^^^^                 ^
```

Output:

```
{
  "date": [
    [
      "09/26/2019"
    ]
  ],
  "fn": [
    [
      "Keith"
    ]
  ],
  "first_name": [
    [
      "Keith"
    ]
  ],
  "ln": [
    [
      "Miklas"
    ]
  ],
  "last_name": [
    [
      "Miklas"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Clever! Nice one. What if I want to parse into more than 2?

Comment: @kmiklas `%{DATE:date}\s*(?<fn2>(?<fn>%{WORD:first_name}))\s*(?<n2>(?<ln>%{WORD:last_name}))`